# How does this put implementation work with q instead of p

Tags: algorithm, f#, functional-programming

We are implementing the `put` part of Algorithm A from *Functional Programs for Generating Permutations* (Topor, 1982). This is our implementation. It passes preliminary tests.

```
// constructively puts a in to p immediately before q
let rec put (a: 't) (p: List<'t>) (q: 't) : List<'t> = 
    if p.Head = q then a :: p
    else p.Head :: put a p.Tail q
```

Our implementation seems to vary from the article's suggested implementation.

```
put (a, p, q) = 
    if p = q then a : q
    else (hd p) : put(a, tl p, q)
```

The difference of concern is my `then a :: p` versus the article's `then a : q`. That is, the article uses `q`.  That seems to be incorrect. Am I missing something or is there a mistake in the article?

Here is the relevant snippet from the article.

[image]

W. Topor, Rodney. (1982). Functional Programs for Generating Permutations. Comput. J.. 25. 257-263. 10.1093/comjnl/25.2.257.

Comment: In their implementation, `q` is a list, but in yours it's an element. I'm not sure why you chose to go this route, but that's the reason your implementation is different.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I chose this route because I am learning how to read and made an mistaken assumption. Thank you for pointing out the mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The difference of concern is my then `a :: p` versus the article's then `a : q`. That is, the article uses `q`. That seems to be incorrect. Am I missing something or is there a mistake in the article?

Since down this branch we have that `p = q`, they should be interchangeable.

I think though that you've misinterpreted the types in `put`, they should be:

```
let rec put (a: 't) (p: List<'t>) (q: List<'t>) : List<'t> = ...
```

Answer (score 2):

In the example as described in the book, `q` is a (sub-)list. In your implementation, it looks like a scalar.